# How do I force the default version of files to update

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app deployed to version 11.  In version 10 there was a javascript file that had a mistake in it that was fixed in version 11.  when I go to version 11 of the app the file is correct in the default version(without 11 in url) its still serving version 10.  I deleted version 10 of the app and went back and looked at the file and its still serving version 10 even thou I deleted version 10.  How do I clear the cache on the server.  This is not a browser issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's probably being cached by appengine's frontend cache. It will probably clear up in about 20 minutes (that's been our experience).

The best thing to do is have part of your build process rename your css/js files with a build version # in the name so that they are always unique.